# Oracle: Find total query run time for multiple query runs

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find total time taken for a query to run (execution time + fetch time). I am using the query below. Is this the correct way?

The sql_text I am using takes a few milliseconds to return results. I am running the sql_text multiple times. V$SQL provides me a single query run, number of executions, and first load time. How can I find total time taken each time the query runs?

> `select ELAPSED_TIME from V$SQL where sql_text = ""`

**Edit1**: My queries vary very slightly, example I am inserting different integers. From V$SQL, these queries have different SQL_ID but I am not able to find them in AWR. Also, is ELAPSED_TIME a summation of all query executions or an average or elapsed time of last query executed?

Answer (score 3):

The column `ELAPSED_TIME` as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/V-SQL.html#GUID-2B9340D7-4AA8-4894-94C0-D5990F67BE75) contains:

> Elapsed time (in microseconds) used by this cursor for parsing, executing, and fetching. If the cursor uses parallel execution, then ELAPSED_TIME is the cumulative time for the query coordinator, plus all parallel query slave processes.

The important thing is that the statistics are related to the **cursor**.

So if the cursor is flushed and reloaded the *total* value is reset and start fom zero.

To get a more complete picture you may use [AWR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/tgdba/gathering-database-statistics.html#GUID-CE73D449-0EE9-4022-B1F1-AA12F0955C03) which basically takes periodic snashot of the statistics and stores them for reporting.

Final remark - typical approach to reference a SQL statement is to use `SQL_ID` (and not the full text - SQL_ID is basically a hash code if the text). You will find the `SQL_ID`in `V$SQL` as well.

Comment: My queries vary very slightly. From V$SQL, these queries have different SQL_ID but I am not able to find them in AWR.

Comment: `ELAPSED TIME` is the **sum** of all queries executed by the **cursor**. Your probem (probably not using bind variables) is that you get a lot of cursors, one for each value of the parameter. Check "bind variables".

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the queries to use bind variables. These are generated queries. There are two similar queries, only difference is the inserted value. The queries run multiple times and I want to find elapsed time of each run. AWR does not list one of the query. Is there a way I can find elapsed time for each query run? Thanks.